# How to pass reference value to the form element?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am showing the list of products that is coming form the database. Now each product list has one button called 'Contact Support' button. On click of that button, a form should pop-up. For each product, I am getting the reference value of the contact details like email-id or phone number when clicked on that products's button. Let me show my code and explain simultaneously,

Here is my script :
 The following is the script that shows the list of products:

```
$list = $('#final_list');
$.post('contact.php', {}, function(data){
    for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++ ){
        var $temp = $('#product_list').clone();

        $temp.find('#product_name h5').html('Product');
        $temp.find('#product_name p').html(data[i]['name']);

        contact_btn = $temp.find('#cont_btn h4');
        contact_btn.data('contact_supp',data[i]['contact']);

        $temp.find('#cont_btn h4').html("Contact Support");
        $temp.show();

        $list.append($temp);
    }  
});
```

Following script is for showing the form once the 'Contact Support' is clicked.

```
$(document).on( 'click', '#cont_btn h4', function(){
    var cont_to = $(this).data('contact_supp');
    $('#ContactForm').fadeIn();
});
```

Following is the form that will be shown:

```
<div id="ContactForm" class='form_overlay' style="display: none;">
    <h3>Contact Support</h3>
    <form action="#">
        <input id="uname" placeholder="Name" type="text" required />
        <input id="usubject" placeholder="Subject" type="text" required />
        <input type="hidden" id="cdetail" />
        <textarea id="umessage" placeholder="Your Message" required></textarea>
        <button type="button" class='button' onclick="submitContactForm()">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Following is the code of function that will be called on submit of form.

```
function submitContactForm(){
    var name = $('#uname').val();
    var subject = $('#usubject').val();
    var message = $('#umessage').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'contactSupport.php',
        data: {
            name: name,
            subject: subject,
            message: message,
        },
        success: function(msg){
            // After success if want anything to show  
        }
    });  
    $('.form_overlay').fadeOut();
}
```

In **contactSupport.php**

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['subject']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['message']) && (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false)){

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    // $to =  // The email that I get from database for that particular product.

    $email = new \Email\EmailTemplate();
    $content = [
        'CONTENT'=>$message." from - ". $name
    ];
    $this->toJson($email->setTo(['email' => $to, 'name' => $name, 'type' => 'to'])->setSubject($subject)->setTemplate('emailDefault')->setContent($content)->send());
}
?>
```

Now I want to pass the value of `var cont_to` to the form's hidden input element, which in turn will pass this value to `submitContactForm()` that will post the value to backend. How can I do that ?
Or is it possible to directly pass the value of `cont_to` to the `submitContactForm()` function ?

Help is highly appreciated. TIA.

Comment: The first thing I saw was it looks like you are doing `$('#product_list').clone()` which will clone the object, but you are not changing the id on it.  As you are not changing the id and inserting it to the page, that is creating invalid markup.  An id **must** be unique.

Comment: It works fine for me. but I will look at it for sure. But for now, that is not a problem I am looking at.

Comment: Oh, its a problem that will bite you in the rear if you don't deal with it.

Comment: Instead of passing the variable to the method called in the inline binding, why not once you have that variable, set whatever hidden fields would be needed in the form, so they are set when it is submitted?  You'd just do that before you fade in the form.

Comment: Thats what I was going to suggest @Taplar ... the single contact form needs a blank hidden input. Then in the on click, it just puts `cont_to` into that field by `id` (since the form is unique, the id should be fine to use).

Comment: @Taplar Can you show me how can I do that ? I already have an hidden input field in my form(you can see in the code). Can you show me how can I do that ?

Comment: @IncredibleHat Can you also show me how can I do that ?

Comment: `$(elementSelector).val(newValue)`  Ref. http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2

Comment: @Taplar should I do this just before I fade-in my form ?

Comment: I didn't want to post an answer with an example, because Taplar mentioned it first. I wont take credit for other's suggestions =p

Comment: I would suggest that, yes.  @IncredibleHat I don't really care.  So long as the dude gets the help he needs.

Comment: Thanks, It worked. Now I am going to change that id thing. Can you suggest me how to do that ?